# Errors when trying a do while loop for a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdoptionClient client = new AdoptionClient();
        client.setName("Johnny Depp");
        System.out.println(client.getName());

        do {
      System.out.println("\nWhat size dog do you want to get!:\n" + "1) small\n" + "2) medium\n" + "3) large\n" + "0) quit\n"
          + "and any other number for non dog options!");

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int choice = input.nextInt();
      switch (choice) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("We have one small breeded dog. A Chihuahua is up for adoption!");
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Here is more information!");
          Chihuahua goliath = new Chihuahua("Goliath", 4, "Chihuahua", "aggressive");
          goliath.printDogInfo();
          System.out.println("To take me home press 5, or 6 or higher for no!");
          break;

        case 2:
          System.out.println("We have one medium breeded dog. A Labrador is up for adoption!");
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Here is more information!");
          Labrador hendrix = new Labrador("Hendrix", 8, "Labrador", "not aggressive");
          hendrix.printDogInfo();
          System.out.println("To take me home press 5, or 6 or higher for no!");
          break;

        case 3:
          System.out.println("We have one large breeded dog. A Great dane is up for adoption!");
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Here is more information!");
          Greatdane toodles = new Greatdane("Toodles", 2, "Greatdane", "not aggressive");
          toodles.printDogInfo();
          System.out.println("To take me home press 5, or 6 or higher for no!");
          break;

        default:
          System.out.println("We are only giving dogs up for adoption today!");
      }
} while (choice!= 0);
System.out.println("Goodbye\n"); 
//Goodbye message so you know your program has ended. This is not necessary.
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a do while loop for the end of my switch statement to loop back to beginning depending on user input. If the user inputs a 5 for yes then I wanted a simple goodbye message. If it was any number greater than I wanted it to loop back to the beginning of the switch. I am confused on how to implement that correctly.

I have tried the do while loop hoping it would allow my program to run compared to without and I continue getting errors. I have an error in a class as well as now I am having an error in the while line at the end which isn't allowing the program to run at all.

```
Dog.java:10: error: constructor Animal in class Animal cannot be applied to given types;
  public Dog(String name, Integer age, String breed, String temperament) {
                                                                         ^
  required: String,Integer,String,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Main.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
} while (choice!= 0);
         ^
  symbol:   variable choice
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

This is my animal class

```
public class Animal {

    public Animal(String name, Integer age, String breed, String behavior) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.behavior = behavior;
    }
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String breed;
    private String behavior;

    public void printDogInfo() {
        System.out.printf("Name: " + name);
        System.out.printf("\nage: " + age);
        System.out.printf("\nbreed: " + breed);
        System.out.printf("\nbehavior: " + behavior);
    }
}
```

This is my Dog

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
 // Fields for Dog class
  public String name;
  public int age;
  public String breed;
  public String behavior;
  

  // Parameterized Constructor for Dog class
  public Dog(String name, Integer age, String breed, String behavior) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.behavior = behavior;
    }

  }
```

class

Comment: You need to call in class `Dog`'s constructor first its superclass constructor via `super(name, age breed, behavior);`. So it makes no sense that you have the same attributes in class `Dog` as well.

Comment: I didn't even realize I did that! I removed the animal file and fixed the dog class so that error is now gone. The only error that remains is the while loop

Comment: You declared the local variable `choice` within the body of the do-while-loop. But you're using it as a condition of the do-while-loop. The variable is local to the inner scope of the loop. It is not available outside the loop. If you want to use at is, you need to declare the variable outside the loop.

Comment: @LuCio So i tried to declare it before and just now, i keep getting this error. Is there another way for me to declare it without reaching this error?Main.java:16: error: variable choice is already defined in method main(String[])
      int choice = input.nextInt();
          ^

Comment: @Elexis: The error says you have declared the variable twice. I suppose you left the declaration within the loop and added the new declaration in the main method. Change the declaration in the loop to an assignment: `int choice = input.nextInt();` becomes `choice = input.nextInt();` Thus you have the variable declared only once. In general: you can declare a variable only once, but you can assign a value to it multiple times.

Comment: Okay so I have to declare input.nextInt(); as well, do you know how I'd be able to declare that part? @LuCio

Answer (score 0):

Create the class `Dog` like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
   /* Define attributes here only dogs have in comparison to the 
      attributes all animals have in common. */

  public Dog(String name, Integer age, String breed, String behavior) {
        super(name, age, breed, behavior);
  }
}
```